# Bootstrap navbar toggle use to add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use **Bootstrap V3** in **Wordpress**.

What I want to achieve is that when someone clicks the `button` in the collapsed `navbar` menu, the `div` with the class `.slider` gets a extra class.

This is the **HTML** from the **navbar**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'navbar-right',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

And this is the **HTML** from the `div` where I want to add a extra class:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      other elements 
    </div> <!-- close row -->
  </div> <!-- close container -->
</div> <!-- close slider -->
```

I've tried this with **CSS**:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse .in ~ .slider{
   margin-top: -246px;
   padding-top: 176px;
}
```

And this with **jQuery**:

```
$(function() {                       
  $("#navbar").click(function() {  
    $(".slider").addClass("sliderMove");      
  });
});
```

The extra class that should be added on *slider* is:

```
.sliderMove{
  margin-top: -246px;
  padding-top: 176px;
}
```

The purpose of this is that the slider that is after/under the `navbar` stay's under the `navbar` when it collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were doing everything fine, but you need to use `toggleClass()` and select other CSS selector that is not `#navbar`

> it also possible to add a delay? Because the class is already activated before the navbar is fully collapsed.

Yes it is possible, by adding  `setTimeout()`

```js
$(".collapsed").click(function() {
  // toggle the class after half second
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".slider").toggleClass("sliderMove");
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
/* just to show in small devices */

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .sliderMove {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Great, it is working! Is it also possible to add a delay? Because the class is already activated before the navbar is fully collapsed.This is the website [link](http://149.210.224.158/)

Comment: afterwards a delay didn't solved the problem and i figured out that I need a animation. I did get itself together, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to hook into the Bootstrap collapse event of your collapsible navbar. There is no need to assign an extra click handler to the collapse nav button.

> [**Collapse Events**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)
>
> Bootstrap's collapse class exposes a few events for hooking into collapse functionality.

Here is an example.

```js
$('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(".slider").addClass("your-class");
})

$('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(".slider").removeClass("your-class");
})
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.your-class {
  background-color: lawngreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="slider"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The button you are are willing to click is having a class `navbar-toggle` and the div having navbar has an id `navbar` . So to achieve the click event on button you have to use the `button` id not the `div` id. So your jQuery code will go like:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
   if($('#navbar').hasClass('in')){
       $(".slider").addClass("sliderMove");
   }else{
       $(".slider").removeClass("sliderMove");
   }
});
```

As you would like to remove the class when you collapse the menu again using same button.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:
(as you required when the user clicks the navbar-toggle button, adds a certain class to a certain div with jQuery)

```
$('body').ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
         $(".slider").toggleClass("sliderMove");  
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <div class="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      other elements 
    </div> <!-- close row -->
  </div> <!-- close container -->
</div> 
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Javascript

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('click', function() {
     $(".slider").toggleClass("sliderMove");  
});
```

CSS

```
.sliderMove{
  height:100%;
  width:100%
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2eLo32mz/1/)**